# How to remove blue links in outlook 2007?

Tags: email, outlook, html-email, outlook-2010, outlook-2007

How do I remove the link (thats wrapped in span tags below) stop turning blue in Outlook 2007 and 2010? I can find other ways to fix them in Gmail, Aple Mail, etc., but not Outlook 07 & 10.

```
<p style="text-align:left;margin-top:0px;font-size:12px;line-height: 18px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color:#333333 !important;">

<strong>References: 1.</strong> March 2015. Available at: <a style="text-decoration:none !important;color:#5d5d5d !important;">http://www.cliniciansbrief­.com/sites/default/files/ attachments/ZoetisCN_Mar_FNL.pdf</a>. Accessed December 17, 2015.

</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worst case, you can go back to the 90's with a font tag with a color attribute:

```
<p style="text-align:left;margin-top:0px;font-size:12px;line-height: 18px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color:#333333 !important;">

<strong>References: 1.</strong> March 2015. Available at: <a style="text-decoration:none !important;color:#5d5d5d !important;" ><font color="#5d5d5d">http://www.cliniciansbrief­.com/sites/default/files/ attachments/ZoetisCN_Mar_FNL.pdf</font></a>. Accessed December 17, 2015.

</p>
```

HTML email isn't known for supporting much CSS at all.